# Do I have to put google analytics script to each <section> when using the Polymer routing?

Tags: html, google-analytics, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I have my site built on Polymer and I have one index.html which contains all my pages, each as a section tag

```
<section data-route="...">
...
</section>

<section data-route="...">
...
</section>
```

Google says that I need to put it on every page (I have only one - index.html), and sections is kind of like separate pages with their own URL.

Do I have to put the google analytics script to each `<section>` or just in body of that index.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED:** If you are using polymer routes like this one (in app.js):

```
page('/discussions', function() {
      app.route = 'discussions';
      setFocus(app.route);
});
```

Just make it look like this

```
page('/discussions', function() {
      app.route = 'discussions';
      setFocus(app.route);
      ga('set', 'page', '/discussions');
      ga('send', 'pageview');
});
```

For each route you need to track in Google Analytics

And add the Google Analytics script only once (in body tag). You don't need to put it in each `<section>`

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with Polymer, but outside of that, the GA code need only go on every "physical" page (more generally, on every page that has a unique URL, with exceptions). If your site is more of an SPA, then you don't need the code for each section. What you may need to do is to send a very virtual page view for each section though, if you want to track when each section was viewed.